# Understanding "having to do with this most important summit"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> If you change your mind **having to do with this most important summit**, please do not hesitate to call me or write.

Source: [Trump's letter to Kim](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/999686062082535424/photo/1?tfw_site=blisty&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fblisty.cz%2Fart%2F91164-donald-trump-zrusil-summit-s-kim-jong-unem.html)

Can you help with understanding the passage in bold? I am not sure whether this gerund refers to "have" as the auxiliary verb (have to/must) or not. Either way, I do not understand the sentence.

Comment: See [*have to do with*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/have-to-do-with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donald Trump is notorious for his spelling and grammatical errors, so much so that it's become routine to mimic his writing style for comedic effect.

In this particular case the sentence is not especially well-written, and possibly not grammatical, but if you replace *having to do with* with *about* it should make sense:

> If you change your mind **about** this most important summit, ...

It's a good reminder that, even at the highest levels of government, not all native speakers will write "good" English. Nevertheless, you have to interpret what the writer *means* to say, especially when the writing includes important information.